# How to sort an array but at the same time have an item selected whenever the page loads in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am creating this application in Javascript https://broward.org/Animal/TagsAndShots/Pages/bioTest.aspx#
so the idea is that Andrew Meyers shows as the first option whenever the page loads and after his name sort the other names in alpha order.

```
var faqItems = $.each(thisFaqResults, function (ind, faqItems) {
                return faqItems;
            });

            var allTopics = [];

            for (i = 0; i < faqItems.length; i++) {
                var filterTopics = faqItems[i];
                allTopics.push(filterTopics.Title);
            };
            var accID = allTopics[0];
            $('.searchBar').after('<h2 id="faqTopicTitle" class="pb-3 font-weight-bold text-center text-md-left"></h2>')
            $('#faqTopicTitle').html(accID);

            var topicList = allTopics.filter(onlyUnique);


            for (i = 0; i < topicList.length; i++) {
                var topicName = topicList[i]
                $('#topicOptions').append('<li class="py-1 pl-3"><a href="#" class="text-dark">' + topicName + '</a></li>');
            }

            var effectIn = function () {
                $('#faqTopicTitle').html(accID).fadeTo(500, 1);
                return $("#accordionColumn").fadeTo(500, 1);
            };

            var effectOut = function () {
                $('#faqTopicTitle').fadeTo(500, 0);
                return $("#accordionColumn").fadeTo(500, 0);
            };

            //includes Polyfill
            if (!String.prototype.includes) {
                Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, 'includes', {
                    value: function (search, start) {
                        if (typeof start !== 'number') {
                            start = 0
                        }

                        if (start + search.length > this.length) {
                            return false
                        } else {
                            return this.indexOf(search, start) !== -1
                        }
                    }
                })
            }

            function createAccordion() {
                var faqItems = $.each(thisFaqResults, function (ind, faqItems) {
                    return faqItems;
                });
```

I tried adding `allTopics.sort();`but it is not doing it for me.

Comment: Please add complete code.

Comment: add only relevant and minimal code, including html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A short function like this will do.

```js
var list = [
    "Neil K. Sharma", "Yesenia Alfonso", "Fernando Amuchastegui",
    "Scott Andron", "Annika E. Ashton", "Maite Azcoitia",
    "Christina Blythe", "Claudia Capdesuňer", "Ben Crego",
    "Kristen Carter", "Rocio Blanco Garcia", "Andrew J. Meyers"
]

Array.prototype.sortAndChoose = function(name) {
    this.sort((a, b) => {
        if (a === name) return -1;
        if (b === name) return 1;
        if (a < b) return -1;
        if (a > b) return 1;
        return 0;
    });
}

list.sortAndChoose("Rocio Blanco Garcia"); //here you choose any name you want on top
console.log(list);
```